# grafana to record last highest value in graph and singlestat

Tags: prometheus, grafana-alerts

I am using Prometheus as Datasource for Grafana.

I am receiving number of records only once a day at a particular time.

1. Display the number of file received for that day . I did wrote query as : sum(increase(query[24h])) . 
   But the graph or singlestat reduces as over time. 
   I need to display only show the value in that particular time data is coming . Because for the rest of the time it is null .

I did wrote query as : sum(increase(query[24h])) .

sum(increase(query[24h]))

Answer (score 0):

In theory something like `increase(query[24h])` makes sense so it should work. However, Prometheus takes that 24 hour range too literally and it only looks at samples falling within those 24 hours. Seeing as how your samples are 24 hours apart, that's one sample on average. And since you can't compute an increase based on a single sample, you likely get nothing most of the time.

There's no reasonable way of getting what you expect out of Prometheus unless you "reverse engineer" it. I.e. either take the increase over 48 hours (so there are on average 2 samples) and then adjust for the extrapolation Prometheus does (i.e. divide by 2; which may or may not be necessary with ranges over 5 minutes).

Or you can use `irate(query[48h]) * 24 * 3600`, which is basically the per-second change rate between the last 2 samples (what you want) multiplied by the number of seconds in a day. But this latter one may be dangerous if you ever get near-duplicate samples (i.e. 2 otherwise identical samples a few seconds away from one another may make it look as if the change over the last 24 hours was zero).

Comment: Hi Alin , thanks for help on this , This gave me help to understand . I tried with range vector 1439m instead of 24hr . I am little closure with the graph .